# data along with file in java restapi

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-rest

I know how to create `RestAPI` .also I can upload individual `file`. But if our page contains `some fields along with file` then I dont know how to create `API` for it.
Even if you don't help with code, your little suggestion will be really helpful.

[image]

so after filling details and attaching files once user `click` on `submit` button our API should be called.

Comment: Share your model service controller snippets you have developed so far so that suggestions can be provided. I believe you would have a file entity with many to one mapping with ur form object. Share those relationships too.

Answer (score 1):

Did this recently. Part of an API backend for an SPA.

```
@PostMapping(value = "update", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> handleUpdate(@Valid @RequestPart("model") UserModel user, @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile image, BindingResult bindingResult)
{
   // your code here
}
```

[image] model is type Text and file is type File